# Facebook playable uploading issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have made Facebook playable ad which work proper on Facebook 3 week before.
But now I am uploading the same which give me issue of "invalid JASON" with console error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://adsmanager-graph.facebook.com/v18.0/act_678937516959220/adplayables?access_token=xxx&suppress_http_code=1&_flowletID=28589&_triggerFlowletID=28590' from origin 'https://adsmanager.facebook.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I don't know what requirement changed from Facebook side.

[image]

Comment: Please do not share sensitive information like tokens. You should refresh it immediately to make sure no one will abuse it.